# Trying to enter data for each string initializer

Tags: c++

My first question here, though I've lurked for a while. Very new to programming, sorry for bad formatting in this post, my brain is fried. I like to do the homework completely on my own, but I'm completely snagged at this point.

We are to retrieve and process data in a scenario where five different types of salsa are being sold. I know how to display the string of salsa types, I know how to process it once the user enters the correct number of jars sold.

I'm stuck on trying to get the user input number of jars sold to appear after each salsa type is listed.

> ex: Enter the number of jars sold according to salsa type
>
> Mild: (User enters data here)
>
> Medium: (User enters data here)
>
> etc.

I can only seem to get user input data to appear after the names are listed:

> Enter the number of jars sold according to salsa type
>
> Mild:
>
> Medium:
>
> etc.
>
> (User enters data here)

Heres what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    // variables
    const int SIZE = 5;
    string salsas[SIZE] = { "Mild", "Medium", "Sweet", "Hot", "Zesty"}; 
    //names of salsas
    int jars; //holds number of jars user enters

    cout << "Here are the salsa types:\n";

    // Display the salsas in the array
    for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++) 
        cout << salsas[count] << ": " << endl;
        cin >> jars[salsas];
    

    



return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post your code as text, not an image.

Comment: If you have lurked, you should know that you should not post images of code - post the text of the code inline with your question.

Comment: HINT: What is the value in `jars`?

Comment: You're overwriting your `jars` variable.

Comment: Sorry about formatting, I figured out how to get the code to appear with little error

Comment: Can you explain to us or yourself what you mean by `jars[salsas]`?  What is that?  Is one of those things an array?  An array of what?

Comment: The salsa string is supposed to be an array that holds the five types of salsa sold, and the jars integer is supposed to be an array that holds the number of jars of salsa sold for each type of salsa. Im currently attempting a fix with hints given here, so far no luck, but I feel a little more informed

Comment: I GOT IT!!!!!!!

Comment: Thank you folks so much, my jars variable was missing the size, I was missing curley braces under the code of my for function, and I needed to count the jars as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
// variables
const int SIZE = 5;
string salsas[SIZE] = { "Mild", "Medium", "Sweet", "Hot", "Zesty"}; 
//names of salsas
int jars[SIZE]={0}; //holds number of jars user enters

cout << "Here are the salsa types:\n";

// Display the salsas in the array
for (int count = 0; count < SIZE; count++) {
    cout << salsas[count] << " : ";
    cin >> jars[count];
}

return 0;
}
```